# How should I call an overloaded extension method?

Tags: c#, overloading, extension-methods

Assuming I have this extension method:

```
public static string ToJson(this object value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, settings);
}
```

And the overload:

```
private static readonly JsonSerializerSettings settings = GetTheSettingsSomeWay();
public static string ToJson(this object value)
{
    return ToJson(value, settings); // (1) static call
    return value.ToJson(settings); // (2) using an extension on "this"
}
```

Should I call the overload with as a static call or as an extension?

Comment: It should be a matter of opinion, personally I would call the extension method as *an instance method*, That is how they are called *mostly*.

Comment: It's a matter of opinion. If you call the `static` method, why use an extension method at all?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - I want to able to call obj.ToJson() and obj.ToJson(settings) as extension methods on object. I don't want to duplicate the logic and therefore prefer to create an overload that will call the other method. I wanted to know which way is better since both ways will work.

Comment: Is this such a bad question that so many people click "closed" on it? I'd like to know why..

Comment: @Amir It isn't a bad question, it's simply opinion based. "Which is better" questions get no love as they are off-topic.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - Which is better has a deterministic answer in this case. I didn't ask if EmberJS is better than AngularJS.. I had no idea that they both produce the same IL code.

Comment: @Amir I understand, but the question came out as "which is syntactically better" since they do both produce the same code.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - I guess most people don't know that they produce the same IL code..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't really matter. It is basically the same. The same method will be called, and even the IL will be the same, since extension methods [are a code feature, the result in the compiled code is the same](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowDoExtensionMethodsWorkAndWhyWasANewCLRNotRequired.aspx).

The only major problem I have encountered using extension methods is the `dynamic` keyword: it doesn't resolve extension methods. I that case you should always use the `static` method. Since you don't do that here, it doesn't matter.